# Which shortcut keys are available in Windows Exporer for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

In the Windows 7 Explorer, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> seems to create a new, duplicate window and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> places cursor focus into the search dialog box.  What other keyboard shortcuts are available?

- Is there one for a new folder (besides <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>)?
- One to place your cursor into the location bar?
- To go up a directory?
- etc...

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft has a great reference for all the [keyboard shortcuts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Keyboard-shortcuts) in Windows 7. In regard to Windows Explorer, they list the following, among others:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> = Open a new window
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> = Close the current window
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> = Create a new folder
- <kbd>End</kbd> = Display the bottom of the active window
- <kbd>Home</kbd> = Display the top of the active window
- <kbd>F11</kbd> = Maximize or minimize the active window
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> = Rotate a picture clockwise
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> = Rotate a picture counter-clockwise
- <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>+<kbd>Num *</kbd> = Display all subfolders under the selected folder
- <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>+<kbd>Num +</kbd> = Display the contents of the selected folder
- <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>+<kbd>Num -</kbd> = Collapse the selected folder
- <kbd>Left</kbd> = Collapse the current selection (if it's expanded), or select the parent folder
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> = Open the Properties dialog box for the selected item
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> = Display the preview pane
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> = View the previous folder
- <kbd>Backspace</kbd> = View the previous folder
- <kbd>Right</kbd> = Display the current selection (if it's collapsed), or select the first subfolder
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> = View the next folder
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> = View the parent folder
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> = Display all folders above the selected folder
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+**Mouse scroll wheel** = Change the size and appearance of file and folder icons
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> = Select the address bar
- <kbd>F4</kbd> = Show Address bar dropdown of recent history
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> = Select the search box
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> = Select the search box
- <kbd>F3</kbd> = Select the search box

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great list of Windows-7 and Windows Explorer [shortcuts](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/37176/20-windows-keyboard-shortcuts-you-might-not-know/).

It looks like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> = `Create new folder`.

To get to your location bar, the article says:

> <kbd>F6</kbd> cycles objects in the current window. In explorer this
>   will cycle between the location bar, options bar, left pane, and right
>   pane.

Answer (score 2):

Some extra keyboard shortcuts that helped me save time clicking. To chage Folder view:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> = Extra Large
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> = Large Icons
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> = Medium Icons
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> = Small Icons
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> = List
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> = Details
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> = Tiles
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> = Content